# RSpec controller test fails for simple route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, controller

This is probably a very basic error, but I am still learing. =)

My routes.rb consists only of

```
WebPortal::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :categories
end
```

If I understand this correctly, this should (among others) map `/categories` to `CategoriesController.index`. This controller looks like

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

The corresponding view file exists, and rails server serves this page fine. But my RSpec test

```
describe CategoriesController do
  describe "GET :index" do
    it "should be succesful" do
      get :index
      response.should be_succes
    end
  end
end
```

fails with the message

```
Failure/Error: get :index
    ActionController::RoutingError:
    No route matches {:controller=>"categories"}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:**

The command `rake routes` gives

```
 rake routes
   categories GET    /categories(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"categories"}
              POST   /categories(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"categories"}
 new_category GET    /categories/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"categories"}
edit_category GET    /categories/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"categories"}
     category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"categories"}
              PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"categories"}
              DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", controller=>"categories"}
```

Comment: What do you get from running "rake routes" when in your project folder?

Comment: @Rasmus: I edited my question with the output.

Comment: I'm still new myself and I am looking at a simple project I have. The only difference between my code and yours is that I have index as 'index' instead of :index in the spec. But that I don't think will do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using RSpec version 2.6.1 because I used the Gemfile from the rails tutorial at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/. Switching to version 2.7 fixed my problem.

Comment: Version 2.6.1 what? to version 2.7 of what?

Comment: Yeah, that is kind of missing. =) RSpec.